# Jhipster compilation error for windows 10

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, jhipster

On Windows 10 I get character error when compiling jhipster.

Windows 10 reinstall,
Intellij Idea reinstall,
I removed the m2 directory and reinstall..

However, the problem still persists.

https://slack-files.com/T03F8LAGQ-FKZDUT24U-621811c325

Comment: Please share your code with specific details and issue

Comment: Looks like a file character encoding issue. Check that your java files are in UTF-8

Comment: Observation: It only affects uppercase I in identifers, and instead of the *I* the file contains the Unicode replacement character U+FFFD. So it could be related to a lower to upper case conversion, run with a locale like Turkish (which would result in dotted uppercase I, namely *İ*, instead of the regular uppercase I), combined with a file encoding conversion to an encoding that does not support the dotted uppercase I. You could try to run the code generation with a different locale.